# Check active div onload

Tags: jquery

I'm using something like this in a layout

```
<nav id="main-nav">
   <a href="#link1">Link1</a>
   <a href="#link2">Link2</a>
   <a href="#link3">Link3</a>
</nav>
<div id="link1">
   some content goes here
</div>
<div id="link2">
   some content goes here
</div>
<div id="link3">
   some content goes here
</div>
```

So when i click on some nav link it scrolls down to the correct div. The thing is that NAV is a fixed positioned menu, and it uses 200px from the top.
the JS i use to scroll is this:

```
$('#main-nav a').click( function(event) {
    var nome = $(this).attr("href");
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(nome).offset().top-198
     }, 1600);
});
```

Ok, so there's this internal page, where the nav links become:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/#link1">Link1</a>
```

The problem is that it loads the home ok, but the div starts from top, under the NAV (because there's no `offset().top-198` when it loads the page.)
I think what i need is to find a way to get the `#link` from the url that loads and make a `onLoad` `scrollTop`, is that right?

Any helps please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something similar to the below, that finds the current hashtag in the URL and then matches it to a divs ID and then animates that ID.

```
$(function(){
   currentPage = window.location.hash;
   moveLink =  $('div').find($(this).attr('id',currentPage));
   $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(moveLink).offset().top-198;
   });
});
```

**EDIT---------------------------------------**

```
var aniFunc = function(a){
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(a).offset().top-198;
   });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
   currentPage = window.location.hash;
   moveLink =  $('div').find($(this).attr('id',currentPage));
   aniFunc(moveLink);
}

$('#main-nav a').click( function(event) {
    nome = $(this).attr("href");
    aniFunc(nome);
});
```

Comment: No problem.. I hope it helped.

Comment: Well, acctualy, if its not too much... it gives me a weird blink when i click the links on homepage , if you have any ideas :P

Comment: hmmm I can't think of any reason. I would try using a bit of object oriented scripting and use the same function for the onload and onclick. Wait 10 seconds and I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank you very much! I found a bit of solution. the blinking was because i wanst using preventDefault on home. So now, my internal pages uses #main-nav-internal and home #main-nav. This way i can prevent.default on #main-nav and not on #main-nav-internalç

Answer (score 0):

You could intitially do something like that:

```
window.location.href.match('(#.*$)')
```

and trigger a click on that element on page load.